# How can I use row.Means() to calculate the mean of several pairs of observations across a row?

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and not versed into concepts and complex function's syntax.

I have a dataframe where I have rows with several pairs of data, some of them are NA. I created this sample df to reproduce it.

```
df=data.frame(site=c("A","B","C"),
              std=c(14,12,18),
              x1.1=c(2,5,3), y1.1=c(4,7,1),
              x1.2=c(4,NA,8), y1.2=c(2,3,2),
              x1.3=c(NA,4,6), y1.3=c(1,5,9),
              gral_mean=c(""))
```

[image]

For example:
I want to multiply the pairs of **x1.1 * y1.1** , **x1.2 * y1.2** , **x1.3 * y1.3**, calculate the mean of the 3 resulting values and finally multiply the mean value with the corresponding row value from column *std*, generating a value that should be on the last column (*gral_mean*).
As I have NAs sometimes, I want them not to affect the mean calculation.

I've used the row.Means() function before without having to calculate separate data pairs, so I reached a dead end here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The DataMunger Guru's motto applies here:  Tell us *what* you want to achieve,  not  *how* you want to achieve it.   In particular, if you know in advance how you are ordering the columns, then  you can apply any preliminary  function on , e.g.,  `df[,3]` and `df[,4]` for your *1-named columns.

Answer (score 0):

if the variables are in order:

```r
df=data.frame(site=c("A","B","C"),
              std=c(14,12,18),
              x1=c(2,5,3), y1=c(4,7,1),
              x2=c(4,1,8), y2=c(2,3,2),
              x3=c(6,4,6), y3=c(1,5,9),
              gral_mean=c(""))

df$gral_mean <- df$std * apply(df[grep("^x|^y", names(df))], 1, \(r) 
      mean(r[grep("x[0-9]+", names(r))] * r[grep("y[0-9]+", names(r))]))
 
df
#>   site std x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 gral_mean
#> 1    A  14  2  4  4  2  6  1  102.6667
#> 2    B  12  5  7  1  3  4  5  232.0000
#> 3    C  18  3  1  8  2  6  9  438.0000
```

Comment: It works great, and sorry to bother again, but I realized that if the column names are something like abc1.1 * abc1.2, it doesn't calculate it correctly, as I see the section of the function you wrote, to be "grep("x[0-9]+"...

Comment: Something like  `(r[grep("\\.1$", names(r))] * r[grep("\\.2$", names(r))])`

Comment: Where did you take the `NA`?

Answer (score 0):

one way to accomplish the same in Base R:

```
aggregate(gral_mean~site+std, 
     transform(reshape(df, -(1:2), dir='long'), gral_mean = std * x1*y1), mean)

  site std gral_mean
1    B  12       330
2    A  14       112
3    C  18       438
```

using pipes in Base R:

```
 reshape(df, -(1:2), dir='long')|>
     transform(gral_mean = std * x1 * y1)|>
     aggregate(gral_mean~site+std, x=_, mean)

  site std gral_mean
1    B  12       330
2    A  14       112
3    C  18       438
```

doing the same in tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse) # version >= 2.0.0
pivot_longer(df, !1:2, names_to = c(".value", NA), names_sep = "[.]") %>% 
  summarise(gral_mean = mean(std * x1*y1, na.rm =TRUE), .by = 1:2)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  site    std gral_mean
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 A        14       112
2 B        12       330
3 C        18       438
```